# scripting out redshift clusters (db objects, data, cluster) for the purpose of cloning

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'd like to script out my Redshift clusters and spin up "clones" using the python script. I'd need all database objects, data, and cluster specific settings.  Anyone have this code yet?  I don't want to re-invent the wheel if its already out there.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review our Redshift Utils repo. It contains all views and scripts to replicate a Redshift cluster setup.

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/

For example, to generate table DDL we provide `v_generate_tbl_ddl`: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_tbl_ddl.sql